# Is there a thing that allows you to easily control which way down a pipe water can flow

Tags: plumbing, valve

I'm trying to design a somewhat complex small system, in which based on the configuration of certain *other* valves, water could be flowing along a pipe in either direction.

*To be clear, given any particular configuration of the other valves the flow direction *should* be entirely fixed.*
*But **different** configurations could lead to that fixed flow being one way, or the other.*

Given the complexity of this design, it would be nice to be able to put in something that *ensured* that the water was flowing in the expected direction. So ...

---

**Do there exist valves which are mono-directional, but where I can** *(by e.g. turning a handle)* ***change* the direction of allowed travel?**

Comment: Maybe this is clear to somebody else, but I'm not envisioning what you want.  Can you provide a diagram or two to show what you want?

Comment: it sounds like you want a reversible check valve.

Comment: @kris Your link isn't working. (It looks like the URL and the display-text are swapped.)

Comment: Is this a system that relies on gravity for flow?

Comment: No. Flow is determined/created by mains pressure. Direction of flow is determined by valves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently. One of several rsults of searching for **reversible check valve**. *Image from flow-rite.com, no affiliation, never heard of them*

[image]

However, I'd suggest re-examining the entire design. When complexity leads to wanting more complexity, it's more often an overly complex design ethos than a need for complex parts.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the keywords to search for!
Agree that the design is complex, but I *think* that's all derived from inherent complexity in the goal :D Once I've finished thinking about all the details, I may put the whole plan up here, to ask if there are any high-level flaws or improvements available. But at the moment I want to check my low-level details first :)

Comment: A valve may have a way to check water from traveling  in either direction but it does not change the direction of the  flow  of the water. A valve is not what moves the water in the pipe. That is accomplished with gravity or  by mechanical means. The valve is open or closed, it does not pump. **What is the reason for wanting  water to travel in either direction (*or blocking it from traveling in either direction*)  in a pipe?** Perhaps there is a simpler way to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You might try looking up *directional valve*, *T-port valve*, and *three-way valve*. These are specialty valves that would likely be for industrial use; not commonly found in domestic water-supply scenarios so not available at a local plumbing or home improvement shop.

[image]